# Refresh linux desktop from CLI

Tags: linux-mint, desktop, nemo

Running Linux Mint 17 with Nemo. We can refresh the contents of the desktop by pressing F5. If some changes occurred to the files in the Desktop folder (/home//Desktop by default) and the desktop of cinnamon is not in sync, then pressing F5 will refresh the icons.

How can I achieve the same behaviour from the CLI (bash for example)? This should be done without restarting cinnamon.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me that F5 was there!  I've been looking for it for a long time!